# Reactivity: change property in array, applied on window event

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-class-components

Simple use case:
Specific elements should get an active class by setting property "active" to true (v-bind:class).
The property "active" is set within a foreach loop, after checking some conditions, within method "handleScroll".

This works, if I call "handleScroll" directly in created lifecycle.

```
<template>
  <div class="c-sidebar">
    <p
      v-for="(sidebarItem, index) in sidebarItems"
      v-bind:key="index"
      v-bind:class="{ 'active': sidebarItem.active }"
    >
      {{ sidebarItem.label }}
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">

import { Component, Vue, Prop } from "vue-property-decorator";
import {SidebarItem, SidebarNavItem} from "../../Interfaces";

@Component
export default class Sidebar extends Vue {
  sidebarItems: SidebarItem[];

  public created() {

    this.sidebarItems = [
      {
        label: "First item",
        active: true
      },
      {
        label: "Second item",
        active: false
      }
    ];

    this.handleScroll();
}

  public handleScroll() {
    this.sidebarItems.forEach((sidebarItem: SidebarItem, index) => {
      if (index == 1) {
        sidebarItem.active = true;
      } else {
        sidebarItem.active = false;
      }
    });
  }
}
</script>
```

---

If I call "handleScroll" from within a window event, reactivity gets lost.

Change

```
public created() {
  ...
  this.handleScroll();
}
```

to

```
public created() {
  ...
  window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
}
```

does not work. The method is executed, but reactivity in template gets lost.

**Question**: How to I set these properties in a global window event and assign them back to view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be Vue reactivity problem.

Please try changing object reference by creating a deep copy using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())`

```
public handleScroll() {
  this.sidebarItems.forEach((sidebarItem: SidebarItem, index) => {
    if (index == 1) {
      sidebarItem.active = true;
    } else {
      sidebarItem.active = false;
    }
  });
  this.sidebarItems = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.sidebarItems))
}
```

Comment: This works. But it also works, if I just assign the unstringified array back to the original --> this.sidebarItems = this.sidebarItems

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the value with Vue.set, as explained in the [caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats) section, like this:

```js
Vue.set(sidebarItems[index], 'active', true)
```

or

```js
Vue.set(sidebarItems, index, { ...sidebarItems[index], { active: true})
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no obviously good reason this wouldn't work, based solely on the code shown here. Vue's reactivity caveat is regarding adding/removing array items, not changing attributes.

I would make triple sure that the method is actually being run, with some console.log:

```
this.sidebarItems.forEach((sidebarItem: SidebarItem, index) => {
  if (index == 1) {
    sidebarItem.active = true;
    console.log('on: ' + sidebarItem)
  } else {
    sidebarItem.active = false;
    console.log('off: ' + sidebarItem)
  }
});
```

If that doesn't give your answer, it'd be best to recreate your problem in jsfiddle. That'll probably show you what you need. If it doesn't, you can post the fiddle here.

Comment: Thanks. It runs. The problem in my example was, that I forgot to reassign the mutated array to the original one --> this.sidebarItems = this.sidebarItems.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use either a computed property or a function which directly gets called from the vue in order to reflect changes. Below code should work -

```
<template>
  <div class="c-sidebar">
    <p
      v-for="(sidebarItem, index) in sidebarItems"
      :key="index"
      :class="getActiveClass(index)"
    >
      {{ sidebarItem.label }}
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">

import { Component, Vue, Prop } from "vue-property-decorator";
import {SidebarItem, SidebarNavItem} from "../../Interfaces";

@Component
export default class Sidebar extends Vue {
  sidebarItems: SidebarItem[];

  public created() {

    this.sidebarItems = [
      {
        label: "First item",
        active: true
      },
      {
        label: "Second item",
        active: false
      }
    ];
}

  public getActiveClass(index: number) {
    return index === 1 ? 'active': '';
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This works, but does not fit to my use case. My example was simplified, just to show the problem. I need a mutation of multiple properties of the array's objects to react on several elements in the template.